# Trying to make a backspace button programmatically to do the same as the keyboard delete (ᗏX) button

Tags: swift

```swift
@objc func searchButtonTap() { 
    searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
    var remove = searchBar.text
    remove = String(remove!.dropLast())
    searchBar.text = remove 
}
```

Also tried two backspaces

```swift
@objc func searchButtonTap() { 
    let name: String = searchBar.text!
    let endIndex = name.index(name.endIndex, offsetBy: -2)
    let truncated = String(name[..<endIndex])
    searchBar.text = truncated 
}
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: I'm trying to implement a search of the tableview at the same time but it only searches when a touch event occurs. –

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to remove the last character of the search bar text when the user taps on back(search?) button.
So,

```
@objc func searchButtonTap() { 
    guard !(searchBar.text?.isEmpty ?? true) else { return } //Making sure that you don't hit the "Fatal error: Can't remove more items from a collection than it contains"
    searchBar.text?.removeLast(1)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, that does actually help to make things more simple. I'm also trying to implement a search of the tableview at the same time but it only searches when a touch event occurs.